# change comment in Rmd document wide in the initial yaml config

Tags: r, markdown

````
---
title: "Offer Optimiser"
output: pdf_document
BBB
---

```{r, AAA}
library(dplyr)
```
````

AAA equal to `comment = "AAA"` changes the symbols in front the the lines of R output from `##` to `AAA`.  Now I would like to make this change for the whole document.  I presume this means adding something at location `BBB`, but I can't find what (comment = "AAA" doesn't work there, and right now I don't have anything else that looks reasonable to me to try).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `knitr::opts_chunk$set()` in the first chunk of your document to set up default chunk options. See `?knitr::opts_chunk` for a list of all options that can be set up that way.

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment='AAA')
```
````

Comment: I had seen this option, didn't realize it would work inside of the first chunk.  Am I mistaken or should, in principle, this be possible in the initial yaml?

Comment: it works for all subsequent chunks, so it will work for the whole document but the first chunk if you add it here. I don't think there is a way to do this in the yaml front matter. This is about knitr (Rmd to md), not about pandoc (md to html/pdf/etc)

Comment: So that means, *no* on the configuration for this in the yaml front matter b/c it depends on backend?